# Prove that there is a dense subset of X on which $f$ is continuous.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, functional-analysis, baire-category, complete-spaces

Let ${\left(f_n\right)}$ be sequence of continuous function on a complete metric space $X$ which converges point-wise to a function $f$ then prove that there is a dense subset of $X$ on which $f$ is continuous.

I think this is application of Baire category theorem. but I am not sure, if suppose my guess is correct, I don't have nicer way to initiate proof of it.

Comment: Theorem 5, starting on page 19, of [this paper](https://www.whitman.edu/Documents/Academics/Mathematics/huh.pdf) gives a proof for $X=\Bbb R$.

Comment: Egorov's theorem gives this quickly: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Egorov%27s_theorem

Comment: I some how agree with you by applying egorov's theorem but we can use it only when our space is finite measure. right? @ christian-remling

Comment: @user145993: Use measures supported by a countable set, with summable weights.